# POST data with user details in mongo db using node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using the MEAN stack with Angular 6. I have a form to submit data into MongoDB. Following is the save function and it works.
It saves the extruded value in the DB.

```
saveExtrudedHeightValue(extrudedHeight: NgForm) {
  if (extrudedHeight.value != "" && extrudedHeight.value != null) {
    this.extrudedHeightService.saveExtrudedHeight(extrudedHeight.value).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the model

```
// Schema for extruded height panel
var extrudedHeightSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String
  },
  extrudedHeight: {
    type: Number
  },

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('extrudedHeightValue', extrudedHeightSchema);
```

Here is my post route

```
//post extrudedHeight values
router.post("/save", function(req, res) {
  var mod = new extrudedHeight(req.body);

  extrudedHeight.findOneAndUpdate({
      userName: req.body.email,
      extrudedHeight: req.body.extrudedHeight,
    },
    req.body, {
      upsert: true,
      new: true
    },
    function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
      } else {

        res.send(mod);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Here is the service.

```
// service for save extruded height 
saveExtrudedHeight(extrudedHeight): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.post('/extrudedHeight/save', extrudedHeight, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Now I want to save data in DB with the current user's `userName`. I can retrieve the current user's `userName` by this.
`this.payload.user['email']`
My problem is that I do not have an idea how to pass this `userName` to post route to save in db.

Here is where I get token.

```
this.authService.onTokenChange().subscribe(
  (token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
    if (token.isValid()) {
      this.user = token.getPayload().user;
      this.payload = token.getPayload();
      console.log(this.payload.user['email']);
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: What's `payload` here? Where are you getting it from? Which file is it a part of?

Comment: its getting from the token retrieving file. That part returns the correct email

Comment: But how are you getting it? Is there a service written for it? IF there is one, you can create a method inside that service which will return an Observable. You can then subscribe to that observable to retrieve the email, and then send it to `/extrudedHeight/save` as a part of the payload.

Comment: how to pass /extrudedHeight/save? Can you explain with an example.Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: Please add some code for your Token Retrieving file that you mentioned in your comment above.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: show us the network output please

Answer (score 0):

You can first call `this.authService.onTokenChange` inside the `saveExtrudedHeight` method, and then use the `flatMap` operator to unwrap the internal `Observable` that would be returned by the `http.post`.

That would translate to code like this:

```
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

...

saveExtrudedHeight(extrudedHeight): Observable<any> {
  const requestPayload = {
    extrudedHeight
  };
  return this.authService.onTokenChange()
    .pipe(flatMap(
    (token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
      if (token.isValid()) {
        this.user = token.getPayload().user;
        this.payload = token.getPayload();

        const email = this.payload.user['email'];
        requestPayload.email = email;

        // Make the changes here to send the email as the Request Payload.

        return this.http.post('/extrudedHeight/save', requestPayload, httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
          );
      } else {
        throwError('Something went wrong!');
      }
    }
  ));
}
```

**PS:** I'm not really sure if this would work though as I haven't tested it out and I can't without a minimal working StackBlitz.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .But how can I send the email to save in db

Comment: I've updated my answer with the same. Please have a look.